# testing difference of means by group

Tags: r, variables, testing

I have a dataset consisting of x number of variables, var1, var2, ..., varx
I am interested in variable 1, var1, a factor with three levels;"a","b","c", and how this is affected by the other variables.

I have done some descriptive statistics with

```
describeBy(dataset, group=var1)
```

and now I want to look at each variable and see if the means for varj in the different grops "a","b","c".

EDIT 1:
Sorry for not being as clear as I thought I was.. 
Actually my problem is this, cause I do know that I want to use a two-sided t-test

```
t.test(varj, alternative="two.sided",conf.level = 0.95,
   subset=var1)
```

I do get a result, but only for the mean of varj, and not for the difference in the different groups.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 2:
Think I am a bit to tired for this.

But this is what I have figured out I have to do

```
anova(lm(var1 ~ varj))
```

And it seems to work out just fine.

Comment: try `?t.test`, `?anova` although your question is more statistics than programming.

Comment: There are a 1.67 million different statistical tests out there. You should know which one is correct for your data; that is not for us to decide for you. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions only. (Though you may try asking on stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a One-Way ANOVA!?

Try this:

`model1 = aov(var1 ~ varj)`

`summary(model1)`

If you want to know which pairs/groups are significantly different from each other  you can use for instance Bonferroni

`pairwise.t.test(var1, varj, p.adj = "bonf")`